# Is there any solution for "too close to the limit" error while finding the longest common sequence?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, recursion, lcs

I'm tryin to find the longest common sequence between two very long sequences, but it gives an error "C stack usage  15924368 is too close to the limit"
Here is the code:

```
lcs <- function(X, Y, m, n, dp) {
  if (m == 0 | n == 0) {
    return(0)
  }

  if (dp[m, n] != -1) {
    return(dp[m, n])
  }

  if (is.na(X[m]) == is.na(Y[n])) {
    dp[m, n] <- 1 + lcs(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1, dp)
    return(dp[m, n])
  }

  dp[m, n] <- max(lcs(X, Y, m, n - 1, dp), lcs(X, Y, m - 1, n, dp))
  return(dp[m, n])
}

dp <- matrix(-1, nrow = nchar(a) + 1, ncol = nchar(b) + 1)

longcs= lcs(a, b, nchar(a), nchar(b), dp)
```

and also is there any way to see the string? This code shows only the number.

Comment: @Kartoos Thanks for your edit but please, in the future, **do not edit the code that you are formatting**. Your edit changes introduced syntax errors that adulterated and invalidated the question, and I almost closed it as a consequence.

Comment: Thanks your consideration, but do you have suggestion ?

Comment: Removing the error without completely changing the algorithm is going to be tricky. Fundamentally, R doesn’t deal very well with deep recursion. — But your code contains two bugs: first of all, you are accessing the characters of the string inside `lcs` via subsetting. To be able to use subsetting, you need to pass the strings as *vectors of individual characters*, i.e. you need to call the function with `strsplit(a, "")[[1]]` (and the same for `b`). Secondly, since you are *copying* the `dp` matrix every time you recursively call `lcs`, the other calls won’t see the changes to `dp`.

Comment: In fact, in the current code you are not taking advantage of `dp` at all, you *always* recompute results. You can check this yourself by putting a `message()` call into the second `if` statement, and you will see that it will *never* be executed! In order to use `dp` you need to make modifications to it globally instead of passing it as an argument (but doing this is not a good idea! A better solution would be to create the DP matrix inside a closure that the function can access; this is a more advanced programming technique).

Comment: `(is.na(X[m]) == is.na(Y[n]))` is also incorrect! It should be `X[m] == Y[n]`!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be better to avoid using the ***recursion*** for LCS, since R seems to have some limitations on the depths of recursions, and recursions are slow sometimes (especially when you need to copy large arguments that would not result in a copy in an iterative implementation, see the comment from @Konrad Rudolph).

---

If you have relative short strings `X` and `Y` to find the LCS, probably you can try the code below

- If you want to conut the length of LCS substring

```
lcsCnt <- function(X, Y, m, n, cnt = 0) {
    if (m * n == 0) {
        return(cnt)
    }
    if (substr(X, m, m) == substr(Y, n, n)) {
        cnt <- Recall(X, Y, m - 1, n - 1, cnt + 1)
    }
    return(max(cnt, Recall(X, Y, m, n - 1, 0), Recall(X, Y, m - 1, n, 0)))
}
```

- If you want to display the LCS substring

```
lcsStr <- function(X, Y) {
    if (nchar(X) * nchar(Y) == 0) {
        return("")
    }
    x <- substr(X, 1, 1)
    xs <- substr(X, 2, nchar(X))
    y <- substr(Y, 1, 1)
    ys <- substr(Y, 2, nchar(Y))
    if (x == y) {
        return(paste0(x, Recall(xs, ys)))
    }
    s1 <- Recall(X, ys)
    s2 <- Recall(xs, Y)
    ifelse(nchar(s1) > nchar(s2), s1, s2)
}
```

---

## Example

```
> a <- "xstacky"

> b <- "@stack&over)flow//"

> lcsCnt(a,b, nchar(a),nchar(b))
[1] 5

> lcsStr(a, b)
[1] "stack"
```

Comment: “and recursions are slow as well” — That’s a myth. Used properly, recursion is no slower than iteration, unless you run into a case (specifically in R) where you need to copy large arguments that would not result in a copy in an iterative implementation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, that's true. Recursion simplifies the process and runs fast as long as it is well designed.